# Missing GridView vertical line. How to add it. in asp.net C# and Telerik

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I'm running my code all alright. I've created the table that you see on the picture, but I can't see the line new **Straight Line** HeaderText.

I'm using ASP.net C# with Telerik.

** But What am I missing to display that line?**

Please help!

**GridView Code **

```
<div id="divMainGrid" runat="server" style="height: 700px">
   <p>
        <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="None" ToolTip="Click on a row to select a setting." AllowPaging="true"
            CssClass="AddBorders" ShowFooter="false" Width="100%" AllowFilteringByColumn="true" AllowSorting="true"
             Visible="true" 
            OnDetailTableDataBind="RadGrid1_DetailTableBind"
            OnNeedDataSource="radGrid_DataSource"
            EnableHierarchyExpandAll="false">


              <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric" AlwaysVisible="true" />

            <ClientSettings EnablePostBackOnRowClick="false" EnableRowHoverStyle="true" AllowColumnsReorder="true">
                <Resizing AllowColumnResize="false" />
                <Selecting AllowRowSelect="false" />
                <Scrolling AllowScroll="true" UseStaticHeaders="true" SaveScrollPosition="true" EnableVirtualScrollPaging="false" ScrollHeight="490px" FrozenColumnsCount="3" />
            </ClientSettings>

            <GroupingSettings CaseSensitive="false" />

             <MasterTableView Width="100%" DataKeyNames="AssetClass_ID, AssetCategory_ID" TableLayout="Fixed">
                <ColumnGroups>
                    <telerik:GridColumnGroup Name="DepreciationAmortisationMethod" HeaderText="Depreciation/Amortisation Method"  HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    </telerik:GridColumnGroup>
                    <telerik:GridColumnGroup Name="MeasurementModel" HeaderText="Measurement Model" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    </telerik:GridColumnGroup>
                     <telerik:GridColumnGroup Name="RevaluationModel" HeaderText="Revaluation Model" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    </telerik:GridColumnGroup>
                </ColumnGroups>
                <DetailTables>                        
                    <telerik:GridTableView DataKeyNames="AssetClass_ID, AssetCategory_ID" Name="CategoryDetails" EnableHierarchyExpandAll="false" HierarchyLoadMode="ServerOnDemand"  AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                        <Columns>                               
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="AssetCategory_ID" HeaderText="Asset Category ID" UniqueName="AssetCategory_ID" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="5px" Visible="false" />
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="CategoryDescription" HeaderText="Asset Category Description" UniqueName="CategoryDescription" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="104px" />
```

<%--                                
                                    
                                        '>

```
                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn ColumnEditorID="colEditMonths" DataField="UsefulLifeMonth" HeaderText="Months" UniqueName="Months" HeaderStyle-Width="85px" ColumnGroupName="UsefulLife">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMonths" runat="server" Width="85px" ReadOnly="false" ViewStateMode="Enabled" Text='<%# Eval("UsefulLifeMonth").ToString()%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>--%>
                        </Columns>                           
                    </telerik:GridTableView>                   
                </DetailTables>

                <Columns>         

                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn ColumnEditorID="colEditChkbox" HeaderText="Select" UniqueName="SelectAsset" AllowFiltering="false" HeaderStyle-Width="45px" >

                          <ItemTemplate>
                              <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectAsset" runat="server" Text="Select"  EnableViewState="true" />
                          </ItemTemplate>
                      </telerik:GridTemplateColumn> 

                   <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="AssetClass_ID" HeaderText="Asset Class ID" UniqueName="AssetClass_ID" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="5px" Visible="false" />
                   <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="AssetClassDescription" HeaderText="Asset Class Description" UniqueName="AssetCategory_ID" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="175px" Visible="true" ColumnGroupName="DepreciationAmortisationMethod" />

                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn ColumnEditorID="colEdit_StraightLineID" DataField="StraightLine" HeaderText="Straight Line" UniqueName="StraightLineID" AllowFiltering="false" HeaderStyle-Width="140px" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ColumnGroupName="DepreciationAmortisationMethod">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbStraightLine"  runat="server" CausesValidation="true"  GroupName="DepreciationAmortisationMethod" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("StraightLine")) == false ? false : Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("StraightLine"))%>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn ColumnEditorID="colEdit_DiminishingBalanceInitialYear" DataField="DiminishingBalanceInitialYear" HeaderText="Diminishing Balance Initial Year" UniqueName="DiminishingBalanceInitialYear" AllowFiltering="false" HeaderStyle-Width="140px" ColumnGroupName="DepreciationAmortisationMethod">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbDiminishingBalanceInitialYear" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" GroupName="DepreciationAmortisationMethod" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("DiminishingBalanceInitialYear")) %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn ColumnEditorID="colEdit_DiminishingBalanceSubsequentYear" DataField="DiminishingBalanceSubsequentYear" HeaderText="Diminishing Balance SubsequentYear" UniqueName="DiminishingBalanceSubsequentYear" AllowFiltering="false" HeaderStyle-Width="140px" ColumnGroupName="DepreciationAmortisationMethod">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbDiminishingBalanceSubsequentYear" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" GroupName="DepreciationAmortisationMethod" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("DiminishingBalanceSubsequentYear")) %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn ColumnEditorID="colEdit_UnitsOfProduction" DataField="UnitsOfProduction" HeaderText="Units Of Production" UniqueName="UnitsOfProduction" AllowFiltering="false" HeaderStyle-Width="140px" ColumnGroupName="DepreciationAmortisationMethod">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbUnitsOfProduction" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" GroupName="DepreciationAmortisationMethod" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("UnitsOfProduction")) %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn ColumnEditorID="colEdit_Cost" DataField="Cost" HeaderText="Cost" UniqueName="Cost" AllowFiltering="false" HeaderStyle-Width="140px" ColumnGroupName="MeasurementModel">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbCost" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" GroupName="MeasurementModel" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Cost")) %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn ColumnEditorID="colEdit_RevaluedAmount" DataField="RevaluedAmount" HeaderText="RevaluedAmount" UniqueName="RevaluedAmount" AllowFiltering="false" HeaderStyle-Width="140px" ColumnGroupName="MeasurementModel">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbRevaluedAmount" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" GroupName="MeasurementModel" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("RevaluedAmount")) %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn ColumnEditorID="colEdit_FairValue" DataField="FairValue" HeaderText="Fair Value" UniqueName="FairValue" AllowFiltering="false" HeaderStyle-Width="140px" ColumnGroupName="MeasurementModel">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbFairValue" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" GroupName="MeasurementModel" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("FairValue")) %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                      <telerik:GridTemplateColumn ColumnEditorID="colEdit_DepreciationProportionately" DataField="DepreciationProportionately" HeaderText="Restatement of Accumulated Depreciation Proportionately" UniqueName="DepreciationProportionately" AllowFiltering="false" HeaderStyle-Width="180px" ColumnGroupName="RevaluationModel">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbDepreciationProportionately" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" GroupName="RevaluationModel" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("DepreciationProportionately")) %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                      <telerik:GridTemplateColumn ColumnEditorID="colEdit_AccumulatedDepreciation" DataField="AccumulatedDepreciation" HeaderText="Accumulated Depreciation Eliminated against Gross Carrying Amount of the Asset" UniqueName="AccumulatedDepreciation" AllowFiltering="false" HeaderStyle-Width="180px" ColumnGroupName="RevaluationModel">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbAccumulatedDepreciation" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" GroupName="RevaluationModel" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("AccumulatedDepreciation")) %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                </Columns>
            </MasterTableView>
            <FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="False" />
        </telerik:RadGrid>
    </p>
</div>
```

[GridView Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0DlY.png)

Comment: Open a support ticket with Telerik, I can't see anything obviously wrong with this code. Also, fix the code snippet here as it breaks unexpectedly.

Comment: That's is alright! Thanks for your answer. I think i got something. do you know anything about: `UseStaticHeaders="true"` under ClientSettings? may that solve my problem or may I make use of themes?

Comment: I know there used to be some issues with static headers and frozen columns but I think they are resolved. Try the latest version (2015.1.225 in numbers, Q1 2016 SP1 in "words") and perhaps things will be fine. If not, open a ticket.

Comment: Great your reference was fine. I 'm getting to my Answer. But You have not add any answer as if yet for me to select it as good answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know there used to be some issues with static headers and frozen columns when used together, but I think they are resolved. Try the latest version (at the time of writing: 2015.1.225 in numbers, Q1 2016 SP1 in "words") and perhaps things will be fine. If not, open a ticket with Telerik.

Comment: Thanks @rdmptn; That solved my problem. I appreciate it